# Find number of roots of a polynomial inside $ |z| < 2 $

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asks me to find the number of roots of $ z^6 - 5z^4 + 8z - 1 $ in the domain $ |z| < 2 $. This looks like a Rouché's theorem question, however $ |z^6 + 8z - 1| \leq 81 $ while $ |-5z^4| = 80 $. How do I solve this question?

Comment: A naive Newton-polygon-type analysis finds 2 roots close to $z=\pm\sqrt5$, 3 roots at about $z=q^k\sqrt[3]{\frac85}$ and one root close to $z=\frac18$, thus $4$ roots inside $|z|<2$. Numerics moves the root guessed at $\sqrt5$ to $z=2.02332..$, making the application of Rouché for the circle $|z|=2$ non-trivial.

Comment: So maybe this is not Rouché's theorem?

Answer (score 2):

A naive Newton-polygon-type analysis finds 2 roots close to $z=\pm\sqrt5$, 3 roots at about $z=q^k\sqrt[3]{\frac85}$ and one root close to $z=\frac18$, thus $4$ roots inside $|z|<2$. Numerics moves the root guessed at $\sqrt5$ to $z=2.02332..$, making the application of Rouché for the circle $|z|=2$ non-trivial.

[image: winding plot]

*plot of the function values on the circle of radius $2$*

---

Graphically, I find that with $g(z)=-4z^4+8z-1$ the inequality $$|f(z)|+|g(z)|\ge 2+|f(z)-g(z)|\tag{*}\label{ineq:rouche}$$ holds for $|z|=2$. $g$ has all its 4 roots inside $|z|<2$. This allows to apply a version of Rouché where $f$ and $g$ have the same number of roots if $|f|+|g|>|f-g|$. Of course, only after closing the hole in the argumentation by strictly proving the claimed inequality \eqref{ineq:rouche}.

[image]

---

The roots of $g$ are actually quite close to the roots of $f$, as the plot of the roots of $tf(z)+(1-t)g(z)=tz^6-(4+t)z^4+8z-1$ shows:

[image]